# Set default values for function parameters in R

Tags: r, defaults

I would like to set

```
byrow=TRUE
```

as the default behavior for the

```
matrix()
```

function in R.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Or, you can just do `mmatrix <- function(...,byrow=T) matrix(...,byrow=byrow)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `formals<-` replacement function.

But first it's a good idea to copy `matrix()` to a new function so we don't mess up any other functions that use it, or cause R any confusion that might result from changing the formal arguments.  Here I'll call it `myMatrix()`

```
myMatrix <- matrix
formals(myMatrix)$byrow <- TRUE
## safety precaution - remove base from myMatrix() and set to global
environment(myMatrix) <- globalenv()
```

Now `myMatrix()` is identical to `matrix()` except for the `byrow` argument (and the environment, of course).

```
> myMatrix
function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = NULL) 
{
    if (is.object(data) || !is.atomic(data)) 
        data <- as.vector(data)
    .Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames, missing(nrow), 
        missing(ncol)))
}
```

And here's a test run showing `matrix()` with default arguments and then `myMatrix()` with its default arguments.

```
matrix(1:6, 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    4    6
myMatrix(1:6, 2)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    4    5    6
```