# Is there a way to set default refresh=0 as parameter in rstanarm model function calls?

Tags: r, rstan, rstanarm

Using R the easiest way to do Bayesian analysis is to load the `rstanarm` package and just use e.g. `stan_glm` instead of base R's `lm` or `glm`.

However, these functions always output very verbous information on the current status of the Markov chains. I'd like to suppress this output.

I have seen that I can achieve such by calling the functions with the additional parameter `refresh=0`, like `stan_glm(Petal.Length~Species+Sepal.Width, data=iris, refresh=0)`.

How can I add this automatically as default paramater without defining a helper function for every single one of the modeling functions. Is there a way similar to `options` or `rstan_options`?

(neither does cover this particular option unfortunately)

I've also tried the approach described in [Set default values for function parameters in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995306/set-default-values-for-function-parameters-in-r) like: `formals(stan_glm)$refresh <- 0`

However, it does not change anything with this regard